# WebUSB navigator.usb.getDevices() empty after coming from the system prompt

Tags: progressive-web-apps, webusb

On my hardware I defined the landing page URL, so my OS shows the little prompt directly when I plug it in and when I click on it, it opens the URL. So far so good.

But now on the landing page I need to request the device manaully. `navigator.usb.getDevices()` returns an empty list. Wouldn't it make sense that the device is automatically connected to the webapp? Because in the end the user already did a manual selection when he/she clicked on the sytem notification..

Answer (score 0):

I've considered that before but haven't checked with Chrome's security and privacy teams to see if they would consider the user clicking on the link to be a sufficient signal that the user intends to give the site full access to the device.

Can you file this on crbug.com as a feature request?

Comment: Hmmm. ok..
From the blogpost from @François Beaufort I thought this might have already been implemented:

```
[...] Clicking this notification will open the landing page.

From there, you can simply call navigator.usb.getDevices() and access your Arduino device as shown below.
```

https://web.dev/usb/#:~:text=From%20there%2C%20you%20can%20simply%20call%20navigator.usb.getDevices()%20and%20access%20your%20Arduino%20device%20as%20shown%20below.

Comment: I just opened a bug on crbug.com. Unfortunately I haven't found the appropriate template for a feature request.

Comment: I've just sent a PR to clarify documentation at https://github.com/GoogleChrome/web.dev/pull/7848